# Descargar archivos planos dentro de un directorio de un servidor ftp0 con ftplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, servidor, ftpclient

Necesito descargarme los archivos almacenados dentro de un directorio de un servidor ftp0 público, para posteriormente poder generar una tabla con datos extraídos de ellos.

Lo he intentado con diversos programas sacados de `ftplib` pero me dan error :

```
import sys
import ftplib
import os
from ftplib import FTP
ftp=FTP("ftp0------")
ftp.login("anonymous",----------)

def downloadFiles(path,destination):
#path & destination are str of the form "/dir/folder/something/"
#path should be the abs path to the root FOLDER of the file tree to download
    try:
        ftp.cwd(path)
        #clone path to destination
        os.chdir(destination)
        os.mkdir(destination[0:len(destination)-1]+path)
        print (destination[0:len(destination)-1]+path+" built")
    except OSError:
        #folder already exists at destination
        pass
    except ftplib.error_perm:
        #invalid entry (ensure input form: "/dir/folder/something/")
        print ("error: could not change to "+path)
        sys.exit("ending session")

    #list children:
    filelist=ftp.nlst()

    for file in filelist:
        try:
            #this will check if file is folder:
            ftp.cwd(path+file+"/")
            #if so, explore it:
            downloadFiles(path+file+"/",destination)
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            #not a folder with accessible content
            #download & return
            os.chdir(destination[0:len(destination)-1]+path)
            #possibly need a permission exception catch:
            ftp.retrbinary("RETR "+file, 
             open(os.path.join(destination,file),"wb").write)
            print (file + " downloaded")
    return

source="/publico/-------/"
dest="/ftp0-------/expl/"
downloadFiles(source,dest)
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> error: could not change to /publico/----/
>   An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
>
> SystemExit: ending session

---

Este otro código  si funciona pero no me imprime en pantalla nada y no me salen los archivos.

```
import ftplib

# Connection information
server = 'ftp0.-------'
username = 'anonymous'
password = '-----'

# Directory and matching information
directory = '/expl/publico/MI_DIRECTORIO/'
filematch = '*.txt'

# Establish the connection
ftp = ftplib.FTP(server)
ftp.login(username, password)

# Change to the proper directory
ftp.cwd(directory)

# Loop through matching files and download each one individually
for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    fhandle = open(filename, 'wb')
    print ('Getting ' + filename)
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)
    fhandle.close()
```

Comment: El primero es recursivo y el segundo solo descarga los ficheros presentes en el directorio actual sin recorrer los posibles directorios hijos. Asegúrate que la ruta al directorio es correcta, en un script no usas la misma que en otro (`dest` en el primero es el directorio donde clonar en tu sistema no una ruta al servidor). En el último código que usas intentas filtrar archivos con extensión .txt cuando el primer parámetro (opcional) debe ser una ruta a listar (puedes pasar argumentos no estándar pero solo si el server los soporta) prueba simplemente con `for filename in ftp.nlst():`

Comment: Gracias lo he solucionado.